# ALB and NLB Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create 2 EC2 instances. One with ports 8081 enabled and the other with ports 8082 enabled.
I have configured the same in their respective 'Security Groups' under Inbound rules and enabled the ports in their respective 'httpd' configuration files.

The use case is to integrate a Network load balancer & application load balancer and further route the traffic to the 2 EC2 instances.

[image: Use Case Diagram]

While creating the target group for ALB, we can use the ports 8081 or 8082 together. However, since ALB uses only HTTP & HTTPS, if I mention the listener ports as 8081, I cannot pick the created target group with ports 8081 enabled.

I understand that ALB allows only ports 80 & 423, however if the EC2 instances can be reachable via 8081 or  8082, how to configure the ALB & integrate it with NLB?

The EC2 instances could have been achievable via NLB. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You can choose any port for the ALB - why do you believe it only allows for port 80 & 423 (sic) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html

Comment: It sounds like you've misunderstood the fact that ALB only supports HTTP/HTTPS *protocols* as a restriction on their default ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). You can use any port 1-65535 with either HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Thanks! I tried combination of the ports. It worked perfectly. I was of the assumption that ALB allows only ports 80 and 443.

Comment: @chamal Thanks for the reply. Yes. I was of the assumption that ALB allows only ports 80 & 443. I tried with 8081 & 8082, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that ALB allows only ports 80 & 423,

That is incorrect, you can select any port on the ALB as indicated by [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html)

Listeners support the following protocols and ports:
Protocols: HTTP, HTTPS
Ports: 1-65535